# How to perform mysql query with goal of returning 2 rows when a single record is found in

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT '12345'  AS AlphabetID,
                 CASE
                    WHEN letter='a' THEN 'a'
                    END AS letter
```

This will return one row with a result of:

```
 AlphabetID | letter
 | 12345    | a
```

How would it be possible to return multiple rows for a given column while retaining the other column field values.

Essentially, adding rows on the fly when the conditions are met.

My thought process attempted:

```
SELECT DISTINCT '12345'  AS AlphabetID,
                 CASE
                    WHEN letter='a' THEN 'a'
                    WHEN letter='a' THEN 'ax'
                    END AS letter
```

Desired Result:

```
 AlphabetID | letter
 | 12345    | a
 | 12345    | ax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for `union all`?

```
SELECT DISTINCT '12345'  AS AlphabetID, 'a' as letter
FROM e
WHERE E.Chem_ID_Login = 'a'
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT '12345'  AS AlphabetID, 'ax' as letter
FROM e
WHERE E.Chem_ID_Login = 'a';
```

Or a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT '12345'  AS AlphabetID, l.letter
FROM e CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT 'a' as letter UNION ALL SELECT 'ae') l
WHERE E.Chem_ID_Login = 'a'
```

Comment: Ah i see, its a matter of creating a duplicate of the query within the query and combining the results. In my particular scenario a 'UNION' is what was necessary as I did not want other rows to be duplicated as a result of all the table joining/more complexity than what was described in the question. Thanks!